# Nodejs+Express | Wordpress | Nginx - Issue with static file serve

Tags: angular, wordpress, nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to setup a Wordpress blog with an Angular Application on AWS EC-2 instance.

The problem I am facing is related to static files i.e, css/js/images/etc.

Angular application is in *`/home/ubuntu/project/`*.
Wordpress is in *`/var/www/html/blog/`*

I wants to setup ***www.example.com*** for angular application and all its routes.
And for wordpress, ***www.example.com/blog*** and all its routes.

Currently, the wordpress is working fine with my current nginx configurations.

**Current Nginx configuration:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /mnt/d/VCN/nginx/html;
    access_log /var/www/html/website/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/html/website/error.log;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
    }
    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_buffering off;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
I can not serve static images for angular application now. If i change the `root` in *server* block, Wordpress stops working. And if I add `root` in */* location, Angular application still don't get the images and return **404**.
I even tried having a separate `root` field for `/blog` location but it was still not working.

I even tried with `/assets/images` thing to make all static files to be served from an `assets` folder but it still does not work.

And if anyone could crack it please care to explain the solution as well. It will be easier to find the flaw in logic and why things was not working out.

I am using Angular-cli so the folder structure is same.

I tried with a simple nodejs/expressjs application too but it was not working. The folder structure for Simple Nodejs/Expressjs application was

```
/home/ubuntu/test/
    |-node_modules
    |-public
        |-css
        |-js
    |-index.html
    |-server.js
```